# Trying to Implement a RESTful application with a Conditional-GET

Tags: rest

Does anyone have any sample code on how to create a RESTful application that gets information from a database? I would like to implement the conditional-GET like Vinoski talks about, I'm just not sure how to go about it. I have created a SOAP application using CRUD and I'll like to try and compare it to GET, PUT, POST and DELETE

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about a) a database in the backend, b) conditional GET, or c) SOAP vs. REST?

Comment: What technology stack are you using? If you don't annotate your question with the proper technology tags you are unlikely to get much help. Also who the heck is Vinoski?

Comment: Steve Vinoski. Pretty sure this is the article the OP is referring to: http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/internet-computing-columns/#2008-6

Comment: REST/HTTP != CRUD. A RESTful application and an application that gets information from a database are two different unrelated concerns. Many web apps don't talk to a database, many database clients don't have HTTP layers. HTTP is RESTful, to write a RESTful web application just use HTTP as it was meant to be used for the transfer of resource state from client to server. Connecting to a database is an unrelated matter and will depend on your database and the programming language libraries you are using.